# Bash - How to split a string with multiple words

Tags: string, bash, shell, loops

I have a long string like following:

`string='<span id="/yourid/12345" class="noname">lala1</span><span id="/yourid/34567" class="noname">lala2</span><span id="/yourid/39201" class="noname">lala3</span>'`

The objective is to loop through each of the 'yourid' and echo the id 12345, 34567 and 39201 for further processing. How can this be achieve through bash shell?

Comment: bash might be a bad choice. If you can, go with a language which has XML support such as Perl, Python, or TCL.

Answer (score 3):

GNU grep:

```
grep -oP '(?<=/yourid/)\d+' <<< "$string"
```

```
12345
34567
39201
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a real XML parser. For instance, if you have XMLStarlet installed...

```
while read -r id; do
  [[ $id ]] || continue
  printf '%s\n' "${id#/yourid/}"
done < <(xmlstarlet sel -m -t '//span[@id]' -v ./@id -n <<<"<root>${string}</root>")
```

Comment: +1 xmlstarlet may not be as likely to be installed, but it's convenient that you can use ad hoc xpath expressions on the command-line.  AFAIK, xsltproc requires you to use a stylesheet file.

Answer (score 1):

With Perl:

```
declare -a ids
ids=( $(perl -lne 'while(m!yourid/(\w+)!g){print $1}' <<< "$string") )
echo ${ids[@]}
```